# Exlude jtable columns from sorting

Tags: swing, sorting, jtable

I have a Jtable with several columns and I would like to avoid that the user can sort it by any data, e.g. the first column header cell shall be clickable (sortable column) and the others not. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou can set the sortable property of a column in the TableRowSorter:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
((TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter()).setSortable(0, false);
```